# What's the name of this component?

Tags: generator

What's the name of the thing that creates electricity if you add hot things to one side and cool to the other?

Comment: Thermoelectric generator (aka Seebeck generator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a thermoelectric generator (TEG). The Peltier cell is the result of the Seebeck-Peltier Effect, and is the most common TEG.

The Peltier cell has two behaviours. First is as a generator: a temperature difference in its sides allows for voltage-current generation. Second is as a cooler or heater: applying voltage and current to the cell through its terminals allow for a temperature difference in the cell's sides, giving rise to a cold side and a warm side.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's not called a Peltier generator. The Peltier effect is the creation of a temperature differential when providing electricity. The Seebeck effect is the opposite, electricity from providing the temperature differential. The devices are mostly the same, and either will work in both directions, which is why most people incorrectly refer to both as the more common Peltier device (they're inside those little travel refrigerators for your car or CPU coolers).

However, there are certain tweaks made to achieve one end goal or the other. For instance, a TEG (thermoelectric generator) would have lower maximum power than a Peltier device, but could harvest smaller differentials more efficiently. I've done some work with [this company](http://www.perpetuapower.com/). They produce TEGs for body heat harvesting, among other applications. They also have these evil looking TEGs for industrial applications:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably a Peltier device sometimes (erroneously) referred to as a Peltier diode because it uses P and N type semiconductor blocks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several "things" that satisfy your description:

- thermo couple
- Peltier Element
- [thermionic converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_converter)
- [combined heat and power plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogeneration)

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to a Thermocouple

[image]

The voltage output is correlated to the temperature gradient

Answer (score 1):

Also known as a "Peltier" generator. Note that the efficiency is low, but increases with the temperature difference across it. Obviously you need to keep supplying heat to the hot side and removing heat from the cold side, or it will equilibriate and stop producing energy.

[An example](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/product/6937030/?cm_mmc=UK%7CShopping-_-Google%20PLA-_-European%20Thermodynamics%7CPeltier%20Modules-_-6937030&kpid=&istCompanyId=f7e7b05b-2daf-4c0e-8825-3633baf8113b&istItemId=xwimtiiit&istBid=tzit) item.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of a Peltier Device. These devices are typically used as a cooling device through the consumption of electrical energy. However if the device is placed into a thermal gradient (one side cold and the other side hot) they will become a thermal electric generator. You can read all about it on the [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling).